# Calculate the variance and the 1st order autocorrelation

Tags: time-series, variance, autocorrelation

The stochastic difference equation is $$ {{y}_{t+1}}=\frac{1}{a}{{y}_{t}}-\frac{b}{a}{{x}_{t}}+{{\varsigma }_{t+1}} $$ where  
 $ {a}>1; $   
 $ {{x}_{t}}=(1-\rho )\overline{x}+\rho {{x}_{t-1}}+{{\varepsilon }_{t}}, 0<\rho<1; $  
 $ {\varsigma }_{t+1} $ is a forecast error, that is, $ {{y}_{t+1}}={{E}_{t}}{{y}_{t+1}}+{{\varsigma }_{t+1}} $. $ {{\varsigma }_{t}} $ is serially uncorrelated, and uncorrelated with ${\varepsilon }_{t}$. $ {{E}_{t}} {{\varsigma }_{t+1}}=0 $.  
  
 How to calculate the variance and the first order autocorrelation of $ {y}_{t} $?  
 The reference answers are,  
 $ \begin{align}
  & \sigma _{y}^{2}=\frac{{{b}^{2}}(a+\rho )}{({{a}^{2}}-1)(a-\rho )}\sigma _{x}^{2}+\frac{{{a}^{2}}}{({{a}^{2}}-1)}\sigma _{\varsigma }^{2} \\ 
 & {{\rho }_{y}}(1)=\frac{1}{a}\left[ 1+\frac{{{b}^{2}}\rho ({{a}^{2}}-1)\sigma _{x}^{2}}{{{b}^{2}}(a+\rho )\sigma _{x}^{2}+{{a}^{2}}(a-\rho )\sigma _{\varsigma }^{2}} \right] \\ 
\end{align} $  
  
 My answers are different from the above ones, could someone give me a detailed derivation?